# Torch. hub and private repos

Tags: private-repository, torchhub

I want to use models from a private repository, that I have access to, with torch.hub.load, but I get HTTP error 404: not found.

I tried setting $GITHUB_TOKEN env variable, but it didn't help. Is there a way to make this work.

Btw, if I change the repo to public, it works well, but I need it to be private.

Comment: It would help if you post the code you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I also had the same issue. PyTorch hub only works with public but not private repo. How can we test before we release though :(